# Need help searching a binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

```
trav.h

#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Tree
{
    Tree *left;
    Tree *right;
    int node;

    static std::map<int, Tree *> allNodes;

public:
    Tree(int n, Tree *l = 0, Tree *r = 0) : left(l), right(r), node(n)
    {
        allNodes[n] = this;
    }

    int GetNode() { return node; }

    void Insert(Tree *newnode)
    {

        if (newnode->node == this->node)
        {
        }
        // skip dup
        else if (newnode->node < this->node)
        {
            left = newnode;
            cout << "left" << left->node << endl;
        }
        else if (newnode->node > this->node)
        {
            right = newnode;
            cout << "right" << right->node << endl;
        }
    }

    int Find(int node)
    {
        if (node == this->node){}
        // skip dup
        else if (node < this->node)
        {
            return left->node;
        }
        else if (node > this->node)
        {
            return right->node;
        }
    }

    // print does an inorder search
    void Print(Tree *root)
    {
        if (root == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        Print(root->left);
        cout << root->node << endl;
        Print(root->right);
    }
};

trav.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include "trav.h"

std::map<int, Tree *> Tree::allNodes;

// trav print
// trav find X

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return 0;

    string cmd(argv[1]);

    // READ IN THE INTEGERS
    vector<int> ids;
    int input;
    while (cin >> input)
    {
        ids.push_back(input);
    }

    // MAKE NODES FROM THE INTEGERS
    vector<Tree *> nodes;
    for (int id : ids)
    {
        nodes.push_back(new Tree(id));
    }

    if (ids.size() == 0)
        return -1;

    // PUT NODES INTO A TREE USING Insert
    Tree *theTree = nodes[0];

    if (theTree == nullptr)
        return -1;

    for (auto n : nodes)
    {
        theTree->Insert(n);
    }

    // PRINT TREE
    if (cmd == "print")
        theTree->Print(theTree);

    else if (cmd == "find")
    {
        string cmd2 = argv[2];
        int num = stoi(cmd2);
        int result = theTree-> Find(num);
        if(result!=0)
            cout<<num<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"-1"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Having trouble creating Find()

1. do an inorder traversal of the tree and print out the traversal
2. find a value in the tree and print it out if found

The first action is triggered when argv[1] == "print". If it is, do an inorder traversal and print each tree node, one node per line of output. An inorder traversal means to traverse the left subtree (if one exists), then print the current node, then traverse the right subtree (if one exists).

The second action is triggered when argv[1] == "find". If it does, search the tree for argv[2] (a string which you will need to convert to an int). If found, print the int. If not found, print -1. The output format should be one line:

Comment: I'm not sure your `Insert` member function works.  Have you verified that works before working on `Find`?

Comment: `Find` must traverse the tree, like `Print` does. So `Find` must call itself recursively (like `Print` does). Your version doesn't do this.

Comment: And your `Insert` function has the same problem. It should be a recursive routine but it isn't. So I agree with Stephen, get `Insert` working before you go any further. Good news is that `Print` does seem to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs.

Your Insert() method only adds the new node on the `left` or `right`. If those pointers are still NULL, this is ok. Otherwise you should recurse into them. There is no recursive call to `Insert()`.

And the `Find()` method also has a problem, which is already found building with warnings enabled (`g++ -Wall ....`): If the `node` value matches the query, it does nothing. No returnvalue, so it will return some undefined value. Missging a `return 0;` here.

Answer (score 0):

I've made few changes to the `Insert` and `Find` methods:

```
void Insert(Tree *newnode)
{
  // skip dup
  if (newnode->node == this->node)
  {
  }
  else if (newnode->node < this->node)
  {
    if(left != nullptr)
    {
      left -> Insert(newnode);
    }
    else 
    {
      left = newnode;
    }
  }
  else if (newnode->node > this->node)
  {
    if(right != nullptr)
    {
      right -> Insert(newnode);
    }
    else
    {
      right = newnode;
    }
  }
}

// 1 if found,
// 0 if not found
int Find(int node)
{
  if (node == this->node)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else if (node < this->node)
  {
    if(left == nullptr)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    return left->Find(node);
  }
  else
  {
    if(right == nullptr)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    return right->Find(node);
  }

}
```

`Insert` check if the current node has already a `left` or `right`, if it has, insert to the left or to the right, otherwise set the left or right. A similar check is done for `Find`. Hope this may help.